# Алгоритм создания информера о днях рождения (PHP, MySQL, HTML)?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Есть таблица на MySql. Содержит информацию о сотрудниках, в том числе и дату рождения. Нужно создать информер, который будет показывать ближайшие дни рождения 5 сотрудников.

Решение не нужно, просто нужен алгоритм. Как бы вы решили эту задачу?

Comment: Дата рождения в каком формате хранится?

Comment: Так а в чем сложность-то? Сортируем сотрудников по дате рождения и выводим первую пятерку. Какие здесь трудности могут быть?

Comment: А зачем сортировать? Мне нужно 5 ближайших дней рожедниях. От текущей даты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих поисков нашел реально рабочий код. Спасибо ВОРОНУ.

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(pd.birthday,'%d.%m.%Y') as birthday_edit
        FROM phone_directory pd
        ORDER BY CONCAT(SUBSTR(pd.birthday ,6) < SUBSTR(CURDATE(),6), SUBSTR(pd.birthday ,6))  LIMIT 0,5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут всё просто. Запрос таков:

```
SELECT * FROM `сотрудники` WHERE `дата`>'текущая дата' ORDER BY `дата` LIMIT 0, 5
```

Т.е. мы получаем пятерых сотрудников, у которых скоро день рождения. 
А дату записывать в числовом формате, а не в 11.03.2015.

Comment:  текущее время в формате Unix timestamp?? и дату сотрудников тоже в таком же формате записывать?

Comment: Верно. И первое, и другое

Comment: не нужно забывать, что сотрудники родились пару десятков лет назад, так что нужно сравнивать месяца и дни от текущей даты. И хранить дату желательно не в Unix timestamp. MySQL прекрасно работает с удобоваримым форматом даты.

Comment: Несколько примеров можно посмотреть [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343807/mysql-query-to-sort-upcoming-birthdays-based-on-current-date).

Я же говорил про вариант:

    SELECT *
    FROM table_name
    ORDER BY DAYOFYEAR(dob) - DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) < 0, dayofyear(dob)
    LIMIT 5;

На SO есть похожий пример, но не знаю что будет быстрее. Хотя в любом штате народу будет немного, так что на скорости все равно не скажется.

А в текущем ответе (даже если сравнить только по месяцу-дню) возможен баг, когда текущее число - 31 декабря, а следующий день рождения будет 1 января

Comment: ВОРОН спасибо ты помог! Напиши ответ приму как правильный!

Comment: Не понимаю, чем мой вариант не устроил

Comment: Ваш вариант не будет работать с последним днем даты. Т.е если тек дата будет 31.12.2014, То он не покажет сотрудников в новом году

Comment: Почему не покажет? Разве дата в формате 20140812003842 не имеет в себе дату вместе с годом? И проверьте мой вариант на практике а не в теории. И почему тогда такой формат даты и времени используют в БД для датирования например создания темы на форуме?

Comment: о, ответ про людей будущего. т.е. вернутся еще не рожденные люди? -1.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, у вас в компании знают дни рождения всех своих будущих сотрудников? ))

И раз так, то чем вариант-то плох? Можно же поздравить/заключить договор прямо в роддоме, главное дату точную и время знать ))

Comment: А в том, что вы предлагаете запрос WHERE `дата`>'текущая дата'. В том то и дело, что в timestamp указывается год. То есть родился он 24.05.1989, и ищите вы WHERE 24.05.1989 > '12.03.2015'. Надо искать сотрудников, у которых день рождения в этом месяце и в ближайшие несколько дней. То есть в вашем случае придется перебрать всю базу попутно разбирая timestamp

Comment: короче, проще говоря на год смотреть не надо, только на месяц и по дням отбираем. Что не понятного здесь ?

Comment: @duddeniska, не стоит принимать ответы, в которых есть явные ошибки. даже если за ответ кто-то проголосовал. Примите лучше свой ответ, от него польза есть он хоть верный результат выдает(кстати выдает?).

Comment: @Yura Ivanov к сожалению не могу принять свой ответ((((

Comment: @duddeniska, надо подождать два дня. галка появится.